# An irreducible character of $SL(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ of degree $(q+1)/2$, where $q$ odd

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let ${\mathbb{F}}_q$ be a field of odd order and $\chi \in {\widehat{  {\mathbb{F}}^{\ast}_q }}$ be the character defined by $\chi(\epsilon) = -1$, where $\epsilon$ is a generator of the cyclic group ${\mathbb{F}}^{\ast}_q$. Consider the character ${\tilde{\chi}} : B \rightarrow {\mathbb{C}}^{\ast}$ on the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices in ${\mathrm{SL}}(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ by
$$
{\tilde{\chi}} \begin{pmatrix}
y & \lambda \\
0 & y^{-1}
\end{pmatrix} := \chi(y)
$$
and consider its induced representation ${\tilde{\chi}}_B^{{\mathrm{SL}}(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)}$. It can be shown that this representation is sum of two irreducible representations each of degree $(q+1)/2$. This is obtained by analysing the idempotents of the ${\mathrm{SL}}(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$-endomorphisms of the representation space of ${\tilde{\chi}}_B^{{\mathrm{SL}}(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)}$.

I am mostly interested in writing down the two characters coming from these two irreducible parts.

Apparently, attempts through writing down the ${\mathrm{SL}}(2,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$-action on the representation space and then finding an invariant subspace through a suitable basis seems a bit messy. Of course the functions on the representation space has a natural basis just by looking at their values on the following right coset representatives for the Borel subgroup:

$$
{\widetilde{T}} = \Big\{ 
t_{\infty} := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},~~
t_x := \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -x
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{.2in} (x \in {\mathbb{F}}_q)
\Big\}
$$

Is there a easier way to find it through the character theoretic version?

Comment: Do you want a reference for the character table of $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$, or a description of how to find the characters?

Comment: @David: I wish to write it down by bare hands. A character table looks like a magic to me otherwise. :)

Comment: Let me Google that for you. First page, here are some lecture notes that do it: http://www.math.toronto.edu/fiona/courses/mat445/ch3.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I looked at it earlier. I think the lemma in page 7 does the job. I confused it with the cuspidal characters.

Comment: Ah, the $(q+1)$ and $(q+1)/2$ characters are much easier to do. Stay away from cuspidal characters unless you can help it.